# How to receive information from an incoming text message?

Tags: android, messaging

I need 2 variables from an incoming text message, the sender and the message body. How do I access them?

Comment: what do you mean by "incoming text message"? An SMS? A message coming from the server?

Comment: take a look at http://droidcoders.blogspot.in/2011/09/sms-receive.html to learn how to read sms. If you need some "variables" from the sms text, that's just working with Strings

Comment: You should be more specific, provide some code samples or at least explain what have you already tried.

Comment: you need to use broadcast receiver for that